# Reducing the lines of code and creating a one liner of the given code

Tags: perl

I wrote a small code to set the system's date/time. I took time in a scalar `$time` and then split that and stored in array `@timeIs`. Then used `$hour` and `$min` to extract out hour and minutes from the array. I think this was a bad approach which is time and length (length of code) consuming. I need some suggestion to reduce the number of steps and make that in one line. Any suggestion?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

print "Enter day";
chomp (my $day = <STDIN>);
print "Enter month";
chomp (my $month = <STDIN>);
print "Enter year";
chomp (my $year =  <STDIN>);
print "Enter time in hour:minute format";
chomp (my $time = <STDIN>);
my @timeIs = split(/:/,$time);
my $hour = $timeIs[0];
my $min = $timeIs[1];
my $date = `date $month$day$hour$min$year`;
print $date;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of repetition here. Why not make the code DRY-er with a subroutine? :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub expect {

    print +shift, "\n";
    chomp( my $response = <STDIN> );
    return $response;
}

my $day            = expect 'Enter day';
my $month          = expect 'Enter month';
my $year           = expect 'Enter year';
my ( $hour, $min ) = split /:/, expect 'Enter time in HH:MM format';

print `date $month$day$hour$min$year`;
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to leave it as is.  You have about 13 lines of code.  That is not a lot.  And by condensing you will only decrease the readability for someone who needs to understand this code 6 months from now, (that includes you).  It is also harder to debug code that is densely packed.  Programmer time is more expensive than compiling time, interpreting time, and running time.  So be happy that it works, and move on to your next task.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the @timeIs temporary variable:

```
my($hour, $min) = split /:/, $time;
```

Comment: Yes, I missed that. Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

Almost equivalent:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $time_elements = [ qw(day month  year hour minute) ];
my $time_ref;
my $ux_command = 'date ';

foreach my $elem ( @{ $time_elements } ){
  print "Enter $elem\n";
  chomp ( $time_ref->{$elem} = <STDIN> );
  $ux_command .= $time_ref->{$elem};
};

my $date = `$ux_command`;
print $date;
```

Comment: That is using references. Thanks for presenting an another way of doing it as there is always more than one way to do things in Perl :)

Comment: BTW there is some error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

One way, asking all information at the same time:

```
perl -e '
  print qq[Enter date (format: dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm): ]; 
  @d = split /[-:\s]+/, <STDIN>; 
  $" = qq[]; 
  $date = `date @d[1,0,3,4,2]`; 
  print $date
'
```

Comment: Why `$" = qq[]` and not `$" = q[]`, or just `$" = ""`.

Comment: @BradGilbert: I don't know. I thought they were similar in concept. I usually use `q`, `qq` instead quotes because I find them visually easier to read. Does it matter in this case?

Comment: [`qq[$a]`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qq.html) is like `"$a"` in that the value of `$a` is placed in the string. So `qq[$a]` is the same as `'' . $a`. [`q[$a]`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/q.html) is like `'$a'` in that the string consists of `$` and `a`. See [Quote-Like Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).

Comment: @BradGilbert: Thank you, I will take a look to that link.